# Difference between Parse objects returned by a query and JS objects

Tags: parse-platform, javascript-objects

I get an objects list `records` from a query using Parse on a MongoDB. Let's say objects are quite simple :

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "age": 33
}
```

I map this list to make treatments on each record (DB viewpoint)/object (programming viewpoint) : `records.map((rec) => {...})`.
But, I can't access properties of rec thanks to classic syntax like `rec.name`, `rec["name"]` and so on.
To do so, I have to use a get method: `rec.get("name")`.

So here is my question: why is that? More precisely: what are the differences between objects returning by Parse and true JS objects?

I tried to parse or stringify with JSON tools but nothing worked...

Comment: Because that’s the way they designed it?  Because it follows the Backbone model design? Because there’s uniformity in access via get/set that makes hanging functionality (like update events) easy, without having to use proxies or generating getters and setters? I’d probably ask them—anything else is guess.